# Remove Hyperlinks Preserve Cell Format

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have some cells in a worksheet that contain *Inserted* hyperlinks.  I want to remove the hyperlinks and leave the "friendly name" in the cell.  I can do this with:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim h As Hyperlink

   For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
      h.Delete
   Next h
End Sub
```

This little Sub works.  However if I start with:

[image]

and run the macro, I get:

[image]

The format of the cell has been ruined!  Is there anyway to remove the hyperlink and leave the formatting alone??

**EDIT#1:**

examining hyperlink properties, I got this to work:

```
Sub dural2()
   Dim h As Hyperlink, addy As String, z As String

   For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
     addy = h.Range.Address
     z = h.Parent
     Range(addy).ClearContents
     Range(addy).Value = z
   Next h
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505162/removing-hyperlinks-retaining-formulas-and-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hyperlink object has certain properties which, through trial and error I established that, for a simple hyperlink to another cell on the same sheet:

- h.Address = ""
- h.Range = "CNN" (actually returns a Range but as the default property is .Value it evaluates to "CNN")
- h.SubAddress = "Sheet1!C1"

As .SubAddress contains:

> the location within the document associated with the hyperlink

I changed your code to:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim h As Hyperlink

   For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
      h.SubAddress = ""
   Next h
End Sub
```

and found that the hyperlink no longer works but your cell formatting is preserved.

Comment: Thanks...............all my hyperlinks point to web sites........following your thinking I got my **EDIT#1** to work...............thanks again!

Comment: For web sites the h.address holds the URL and h.SubAddress = "". I guess to cover both web addresses and internal sheets addresses you could set both h.Address = "" and h.SubAddress = "".